# Token Distribution Calculation

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

If I have a Contract A receiving 50000 'XXX' tokens from a contract B, those tokens are supposed to be distributed across 5 whitelisted users who has pooled 'xx' Ether into contract A, how can I make sure they get the correct amount of tokens? not sure how to calculate this, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
for (uint i = 0; i < whitelistedOwners.length; i++) {
    ethBalance[whitelistedOwners[i]] * 10000 / totalEthInvested
}
```

which will give you a percent (because solidity only handle integer, I multiplied by 10000 to have 4 decimal numbers available) and then multiply this result by the 
total tokens available

Comment: "because solidity only handle integer", I don't believe this is necessary, solidity handles integers in same way, either way, however it does allow us to work with less zeroes